# Consistency during Windows 7 system image creation

Tags: windows-7, disk-image, windows-7-backup

On Windows 7 I am creating a system image of the system drive (C: in my case) onto an external USB harddisk.  The process is taking long (has been running for an hour now).

My question: I am taking care not to make any changes to the C: drive while the system image is being created (i.e. I am not creating any files on the desktop, etc.).  But surely, there will be changes to the system drive, because I am accessing the web and therefore, the browser is updating its cache, etc.  How does Windows maintain consistency during the image create operation?  Am I being overly cautious by not creating any files?  Or should I not even run a browser while the image create is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get an idea of how it's handling open files and files created during the image backup, read up on Windows' [Shadow Copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) mechanisms, and how they work.

From [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968832(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS) is a set of COM interfaces that
>   implements a framework to allow volume backups to be performed while
>   applications on a system continue to write to the volumes.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy):

> Shadow Copy (also known as Volume Snapshot Service, Volume Shadow
>   Copy Service or VSS), is a technology included in Microsoft
>   Windows that allows taking manual or automatic backup copies or
>   snapshots of data, even if it has a lock, on a specific volume at a
>   specific point in time over regular intervals.

Comment: +1 Thank you, will read both sources.  But a preliminary feeling I get from your answer and the brief synopses is that consistency is provided for by Windows.  Would that be a fair statement?  Thanks again.

Comment: Basically it takes a copy of the file system and backs that up instead of the "live" file system. That way you can have files open a the time.  Any system created files created during backup aren't going to matter.  User-created files creating during backup should be checked and confirmed they were added to the backup (if that's what's wanted).

Comment: Thank you so much.  Not only did I get my answer, also learned the existence of the Shadow Copy technology.  This is the best type of answer, where one learns more than what was originally asked.